# In highcharts's stacked bar chart, how can I remove the white space between different

Tags: highcharts

I have a stacked bar using highcharts. From the jsfiddle example, you can see that there is a white line between the green and blue? Is it possible to remove this? It triggers some issues in pdf.

http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/e777hgev/

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
    return this.value;
    },
    style: {
           color: 'black',
           fontFamily: 'DINPro',
           fontSize: '7.76px',
           fontWeight: 'normal'
          }
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be removed with the [`plotOptions.bar.borderWidth`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.borderWidth) parameter. It defaults to 1px. You can set it like this to remove the border:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    animation: false
},
```